# JsTestDriver fails to capture Metro IE10 browser on windows8 machine

Tags: microsoft-metro, js-test-driver

JsTestDriver fails to capture Metro IE10 browser on windows8 machine. The URL gets launched in the Metro IE10 browser but intermittently fails to capture the browser. Thus, no tests are being run. The desktop browser gets captured but the Metro browser doesn't. Is this is a known issue? Is there a workaround?

Comment: I remember having some similar issues with jsTestDriver, and force-killing IE before and after test execution to ensure clean environment solved at least most of the issues (`powershell kill -Name iexplore -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`). Was running the tests in desktop IE though, but probably the running mode of the browser doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I tried "powershell kill -Name iexplore -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue" and running the tests and it didn't help. The desktop browser gets captured but the Metro browser doesn't. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I found out the issue. JSTestDriver launches two tabs in Metro IE10 and it is not able to capture two tabs at the same time. I asked a [different question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24810897/how-to-disable-tabbed-browsing-for-ie10-modern-ui) for this issue.